# Is there anything "wrong" with putting javascript on an asp.net form rather than in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, architecture

I am writing an asp.net application that has multiple web forms, each with different purposes and controls. During development I put all of the javascript needed on the form at the bottom of the form in  tags (button event handlers, validation, some custom jQuery control handlers, etc). I do have some javascript in external files, for instance if I have functions that are not specific to the individual form or functions that I reuse.

Now that we are getting close to the release date, I wonder if I should put this javascript inside of a separate file. Thinking about it on my own, it would be easier to maintain having all the functionality of the form easily accessible in the 1 file. However in most of the web stuff I see, the javascript is generally in an external file.

I would like to see if anyone has any views on this, one way or the other.

Comment: If it's in a separate file, it can be cached and will reduce bandwidth. The browser won't have to redownload the file everytime. If it's embedded in the form, you're sending the JS up and down with every request. Of course, speed may not be that important to you, or perhaps the performance cost is negligible.

Comment: When you later change the JavaScript, client browsers will often continue to display the old version from their cache. To avoid this, you can change the name of the JavaScript file and update the form with the new file name.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of separate javascript files is the caching-behaviour of web browsers, which results in faster page load times after the initial page load for following requests to that page. Also you can minify them to reduce load times.
Therefor it is recommended to put javascript (and also CSS) into separate files. As a second recommendation one would deploy those files on faster servers (CDN).

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET web forms put Javascript inline in the form (e.g. __doPostBack).  So it's not the end of the world if you do it this way (this is not the case with MVC).

Modern web sites strive for "unobtrusive script" which means that script is not allowed inline in the HTML.   There are several reasons for this:

1. Javascript file can be cached by the browser which improves performance
2. Javascript file can be minified which improves performance
3. HTML doesn't contain as much unrenderable code, which makes it easier to achieve WAI or 508 compliance (easier for screenreaders to read).
4. If you are following [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) techniques then unobstrusive is also better as the site should be designed not to rely on script being enabled.